# location of a mobile device using only mobile signal strength?

Tags: android, mobile, location, signal-strength

can an app be written to get the approximate location of a mobile device using only mobile signal strength from different mobile towers? I mean is this data accessible to developers or restricted to the service provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Your can obtain either GPS or Network location, or two at a time.
The permission to get location from Cell Towers or WI-FI is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Just register a listener and get the updates

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

manager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60, 10, listener);
```

Comment: @thedjaney yes, it is available while your SIM card is working (e.g. you can make and receive phone calls). The GPRS/EDGE is not required for this service.

Comment: I remembered this working for me months ago, but now it doesn't. That's why I speculated it only works with data network. In that case, this is dependent on the status of the cell towers itself?

Comment: @thedjaney it should work whenever your signal is reachable. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/locating-cell-phone-owners-the-non-gps-way/